# Harborth conjecture and polyhedra

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

Harborth conjecture state that every planar graph can be drawn on a plane only using staight line segments of rational or integral edge length.
( There is a good mathoverflow page for this conjecture, 
[Integral straight-line embeddings of planar graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163845/integral-straight-line-embeddings-of-planar-graphs) )

Due to Steinitz theorem,  every 3-connected planar graph, so called **polyhedral graph** , can be realized as an edge graph of a convex polyhedron. Moreover, for every polyhedral graph, it turned out that we can find a realization in Euclidean 3-space only on integer coordinates.

My question is, in some sense, a variant of Harborth conjecture for Steinitz theorem, i.e.

> Every polyhedral graph can be realized as a Euclidean convex
>   polyhedron in which the edge lengths are all integers.

It still seems to be difficult to answer as like Harborth's original conjecture.

> Have there been a study for this question?